# what is the lexical scope of an object?

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope, executioncontext

I've been reading a little bit into execution contexts and lexical scoping. From my understanding,
if a function is declared, it will have a reference to the lexical environment (LE) that defined that function. for example,

```
var x = 20;
function foo() { 
  console.log(x);
}
```

So the reason why foo has access to variable x is because foo's LE has a reference to the LE which created foo which is the global LE so it can search through the scope chain until it finds x.

however for the following snippet:

```
var stacy = {
  name: 'stacy',
  age: 33,
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

1. What is the LE of the object stacy? (I believe it would be the global LE)
2. What is the LE of the sayName()? (if I omit the "this" keyword, why couldn't it find the variable "name" when the function couldn't find "name" in its own LE)?

Comment: Lexical scoping pertains to code, not objects. The code in `sayName()` has a lexical scope. Also referencing `this` is a whole other thing than lexical scope.

Comment: @Pointy so what is the lexical scope of sayName?

Comment: @james any variable that `sayName` tries to access that isn't directly defined in the `setName` function will look in the global scope

Comment: @Samathingamajig more accurately it will look within the same scope as the containing object is declared in. @james object properties are not variables, so the function won't even look at them unless you access them as properties, ie `stacy.name` (in which the function will find `stacy` in the outer scope)

Comment: Object properties in a situation like your example are not part of any lexical scope. They are properties of an object, and they require a reference to the object in order to be accessed.

Comment: Ok thank you guys :) it's much more clear to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use "scope" instead of "LE" here, as the former is more common in JavaScript learning resources.

Functions have their own scope; objects do not. So while (1) the scope of `stacy` is indeed the global scope, (2) the code of `sayName` runs in its own scope, for which the parent scope is the global scope. `this.name` works because non-arrow functions have an additional binding `this` added to their scope, but `name` doesn't work because the object isn't a scope, it's just a data structure with a 'name' property. `stacy.name` would work, and you could declare a `name` variable with another `var` or `let` statement that would work in either scope.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```js
var x = 20;

function foo() {
  console.log(x);
  console.log(this.x);
}

foo();
```

In the above example, if we do either `console.log(x)` or `console.log(this.x)`, it will print the same value. Why so? Because the x is available as a variable to the function `foo` in its parent scope, it is also available as a property in the global object. The parent object for `foo` is the global object as it is defined and the function created using the `function` keyword has a bound context of its parent object by default. Now, look at the second example.

Example 2:

```js
var stacy = {
  name: 'stacy',
  age: 33,
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(stacy.name);
  }
}

stacy.sayName();
```

In the second example, the `console.log(name)` and `console.log(this.name)` will not be equal but `console.log(this.name)` and `console.log(stacy.name)` will be equal as per above example's logic.

And the story will be different if use `arrow function` in place of the `function` keyword. In arrow function, `this` keyword refers to the global object.

Comment: how did you second example not throw a reference error when calling console.log(name)

Comment: Anything which is not defined in any of the available scopes in js will have a value undefined. But here in this case of StackOverflow's editor, there might be some definition already available in any of the wrapping js scripts.

Comment: Also, js will not throw reference errors for an undefined variable. But if you try something like name.x, this will throw an error.